# PLSQL populate a table with all dates within two dates

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I'm trying to populate a table with dates from January 1 1960 to December 2020. I tried a writing a query however I'm quite new to plsql that I'm afraid I must of messed up somewhere as this does nothing.

```
DECLARE
    start_date DATE;
    end_date DATE;
BEGIN
    start_date := '01-jan-1960';
    end_date := '31-dec-2020';

    LOOP
        INSERT INTO samp VALUES(start_date);
        start_date := start_date + 1;
        EXIT WHEN start_date = end_date;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL is totally unnecessary in this case, use simple command:

```
INSERT INTO samp (start_date)
SELECT DATE'1959-12-31' + LEVEL "DATE" FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATE'2020-12-31' - DATE'1959-12-31'
```

UPDATE:

You can do much more with the data using SQL. PL/SQL is more used when you do something you can't do with SQL, typically just controlling the flow of SQL commands.

Anyway, your implementation is almost fine.

```
DECLARE
    start_date DATE;
    end_date DATE;
BEGIN
    start_date := DATE'1960-01-01'; -- Don't rely on implicit conversion!
    end_date := DATE'2020-12-31';

    LOOP
        INSERT INTO samp /* add column list here */ VALUES (start_date);
        start_date := start_date + 1;
        EXIT WHEN start_date = end_date + 1; -- last date should be included
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Actually is there a way to do this with plsql? I need to do other stuff with the data as well.